# How and where to install a module in python from github

Tags: python, django, python-import

i need to install a module (pyrise) from [github](https://github.com/nicoladj77/pyrise/). This is because i need to modify it and later on commit the changes and ask for a pull request.

If i install with pip i get the usual pyrise folder with the `__init__.py` at root level.

So i unistalled with pip and dis ( in the `site-packages` folder )

```
git clone git@github.com:nicoladj77/pyrise.git
cd pyrise
python setup.py install
```

this installed correctly everything, but now i have a `pyrise` folder under `site-packages` and another `pyrise` folder inside `pyrise`.
And the first `pyrise` has an empty `__init__.py` and for this reason when i do

```
import pyrise
```

i can't access any object, because the proper `__init__.py` is inside the second `pyrise` folder.

What am i doing wrong?Am i installing it in the wrong dir?

Comment: Remove everything and install it using pip: ``pip install -e git+https://github.com/nicoladj77/pyrise.git#egg=pyrise``

Comment: This fails with 
`InstallationError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe" clone -q https://github.com/nicoladj77/pyrise.git C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\src\pyrise failed with error code 1 in None`

Comment: Oh your on windows. The command above works on a unix system inside a python virtual environment. I don't use windows so can't really help you with your error but I don't see why it wouldn't work :(

Comment: I'm using Windows as well and that command works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing it with `develop`:

```
git clone git@github.com:nicoladj77/pyrise.git
cd pyrise
python setup.py develop
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did.

Comment: What was the error you got when you ran `import pyrise`? I mean this worked for me.

Comment: I got no error, it simply doesn't import anything. I can't access the Highrise class.

Comment: Two pyrise folders are created, nested, the real __init__.py is in the second nested folder.

Comment: Right right! So what would be a proper test of success instead of `import pyrise`?

Comment: Something like
`from pyrise import *  
Highrise.set_server('my-server')`

Comment: From the command line it's working. It's aptana then. Thanks fo rthe suggestion