# How to install a Python module on Windows 8.1 from Github or google code

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install [this python module](https://github.com/depl0y/pybonjour-python3) from github. Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081724/how-and-where-to-install-a-module-in-python-from-github) I tried

```
git clone https://github.com/depl0y/pybonjour-python3.git
cd pybonjour
python setup.py develop
```

but I get `invalid command develop`

Trying without develop gets me: `error no command supplied`

So, any ideas on how I can install it?  Also, for my own reference, because it is not much different, if I download the zip from google code, and I have the `readme`, `test` and `setup.py` files. Where do I put them, or how do I install them?

This is obviously for modules that can not be installed via pip

Comment: Try `python setup.py install`?

Comment: did you tried `python setup.py install` ?

Comment: Wow. There you have it.  Sorry, never did that before. Can I now delete the original folder (that which I downloaded)?